# WordPress Subcategory listing with Post Title

Tags: wordpress

I would like to create a tutorial website using word press.
How can we display subcategory with all its post title in a page.
Consider,I have main navigation(Category) as **Lessons** and it has different subcategories like *Chapter1,Chapter2,Chapter3 and so on...*.Here I need to display all subcategories under Lessons with titles of its own posts.Already i tried with

```
wp_list_categories('child_of=10')
```

But, by using the same how can we retrieve each post title..
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for spending time on my question.
I got the right way to go forward.This may help someone.

http://iamnotagoodartist.com/how-to/wordpress-how-to-sort-category-archive-posts-by-subcategory

Comment: Edited to remove the part of the URL which points to comment instead of post. Anyway, glad to know that you found a solution!